# Plugin development, add content directly in body on every page?

Tags: php

I have to develop a simple plugin that add simple a text *directly* in body and on *every page*, the problem is i see this content only on content pages, but don't on pages like: flexicontent & virtuemart
For it i use event:

```
onContentPrepare ($context, &$article, &$params, $page) {}
```

Type is "system", what i have to do to enable it on all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, flexicontent and Virtuemart don't trigger the `onContentPrepare` event. That event is something extension need to include themself. It's not automatically done by Joomla.

If you need to have it on each page, then your better using a system event which is executed by Joomla itself.

Comment: You mean my plugin type should stay "system" and i can use simple: onBeforeRender() ?

Comment: For example, yes. Depending what exactly you do :)

Comment: now is only on hikashop product listing missing, is there any "hack" or something like this to add it also on category list?

Comment: `onBeforeRender` should work on all pages. It's called by the application rendering method itself. Now I don't know how hikashop works internally, maybe it uses AJAX or has some funny code otherwise?

Comment: No, not ajax, the homepage on the web has k2 item type, and there is also missing.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual code. I never used those components so I don't know what they do.
You could ask their support and see if they can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a long shot, but can you try replacing:

```
$page
```

with:

```
$page = 0
```

So it will look like this:

```
onContentPrepare ($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0) 
{

}
```